# Oauth 1.0a not working on Play! 2.5.3 / Scala

Tags: scala, oauth, playframework, quickbooks-online, intuit-partner-platform

Play! 2.5.3 / Scala
Windows 10 (also tested on Mac OS & Linux)

I'm building OAuth 1.0a functionality into my Play! application (mature 2+ years old application) and QuickBooks Online.  I have successfully built the first part that authenticates and returns a valid token & secret, which I then store in my database.

The problem I'm encountering is when I try to make API calls signed with the token.  First of all, I know the token is good and valid since testing it on https://www.hurl.it/ returns the expected data.  However, when I call the same API programmatically from inside my Play! application, the token/signature is rejected (i.e. I get message saying I have to authenticate).

Here is my code sample that makes the API call.  I'm at wits end, i've tried everything I can think of...its reassuring to know that the token is validate when using hurl, but I cannot for the life of me figure out the problem within Play!

```
  def testWS = Action.async {
    val HEADERS = List("Accept" -> "application/json, format=json", "Content-Type" -> "application/json", "Accept-Encoding" -> "gzip, deflate")

    val consKey = ConsumerKey("q********************D", "G********************b")
    val reqToken = RequestToken("q********************t", "d********************7")
    val oauthCalc = OAuthCalculator(consKey, reqToken)

    ws.url("https://appcenter.intuit.com/api/v1/connection/reconnect")
    //.withHeaders(HEADERS: _*)
    .sign(oauthCalc)
    .get
    .map{ resp => Ok(resp.body) }
  }
```

Here's what the resulting headers look like:
Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="q********************D", oauth_token="q********************H", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_signature="zt34J%2BubLgpT%2FdTG8bXj2SWdRRE%3D", oauth_timestamp="1465414901", oauth_nonce="YIiN2lxGnNMhDs9pF3HlBQ%3D%3D", oauth_version="1.0"
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost:9000
Accept: */*
User-Agent: AHC/1.0

Comment: More info...our code base works when accessing other OAuth Provider endpoints...but not Intuit...so the question now is...what does Intuit do differently in their implementation of OAuth??